# Core-Plot: Reloading data in just one of two plots

Tags: core-plot, reloaddata

I have a graph with two plots. The first plot, CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot, is very data intensive and only has to be created once.

The second plot, CPTScatterPlot *dotPlot, on the other hand, is only a single point that moves across the graph in response to changes in a slider. I only have to refresh this plot.

I have been using [graph reloadData] at the end of my slider method, but that must refresh both plots and performance suffers greatly. What is the syntax for reloading just one plot?

Also, might it be possible to refresh only when the slider stops moving rather than refresh for every value of the slider between starting and stopping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Also, might it be possible to refresh only when the slider stops moving rather than 
>   refresh for every value of the slider between starting and stopping?

This can easily be achieved by unsetting the 'Continuous' flag in the state part of the slider. Look in the xib or set it dynamically in your code:

Mac:

```
[yourSlider setContinuous:NO];
```

iOS:

```
yourSlider.continuous=NO;
```

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed this option. There are several places where this might be appropriate in my other apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `-reloadData` on individual plots, too.

```
[dotPlot reloadData];
```

Comment: Eric, I don't see how this can work and it doesn't. The graph and plot code is in the method -(void)viewDidLoad method while the slider code that changes the array of data to be plotted by CPTScatterPlot *dotPlot is in another method, - (IBAction)selectRisk:(id)sender.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to either the graph or the plot in an instance variable. If you have a reference to the graph, use the `-plotAtIndex:` or `-plotWithIdentifier:` method to get a reference to the dot plot.